# there are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation

Tags: java, hadoop

I have configured hadoop-2.7.2 with pseudo node cluster in windows. I have created a client by copying hadoop package to another machine.

I can able to list, create, delete directory from client. But when i run example using below command

`hadoop jar %HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\mapreduce\hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.2.jar wordcount /names /names1`

getting exception as below,

`org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/Kumar/.staging/job_1455644013935_0008/job.jar could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1). There is 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation.`

But when i run the same command in hadoop running node, it executed successfully.

Someone help me to submit job from client machine without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your datanodes are full. Could you please check disk space?

Comment: If i run the same command in the hadoop running machine, then it works fine. I have more space in datanode.